# Javascript direcionar para uma página e imprimir (fisicamente)

Tags: javascript

Bom dia.
Estou iniciando em javascript, mas preciso urgente aprender uma tarefa, que ao meu ver parece relativamente fácil, mas não estou conseguindo pegar.
Seguinte:

Tem o site exemplo.com.br/2.html

Eu preciso criar um javascript que leve o usuário (no caso eu) da página 3.html ao 100.html e a cada página que carregar, imprimi-la automaticamente.

Por enquanto eu consegui chegar ao código:

```
window.location.href = "exemplo.com.br/2.html";window.print()
```

Mas quando eu coloco esse código pra rodar, imprime a página que eu estou no momento e depois disso sou direcionado para a página do código, e não ao contrário, como eu queria que fosse.
Mas, fora isso, como eu mando o navegador ir para a próxima página depois que imprimir?

Comment: Se essa tela for acessada somente por esse caminho, pode colocar na própria página o `window.print()`. Olhe a minha escrita!!

Comment: Por que você não coloca o comando `window.print()` ao carregar a pagina que foi direcionada (no evento `onload`)? No seu caso 2.html, 3.html e assim por diante. Dessa forma, quando redirecionar e a página for carregada vai imprimir

Comment: Ricardo, tentei deixar assim: window.onload = print() mas continua imprimindo antes de carregar. Pode me ajudar? (estou começando JS agora)

Comment: Cara, acho que é melhor você gerar uma página só no server com todo o conteúdo e nessa página, dar o window.print(). Explico: Cada vez que fizer isso, o usuário precisa confirmar a impressão e as vezes até, dependendo, configurá-la. Veja se vale realmente a pena fazer assim...